# How should I struct my Firebase data (base- & movement-data)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I've created an android app with Java and I use a Firebase realtime-database. Via REST, I get JSON-data for cities. "Data" means:

1. **base data** like the city-id, name or population. They rarely change. This is represented in my model class "BaseData".
2. **(movement) data** which changes every day. The class is called "CityData".

*BaseData* is currently part of the *CityData*:

```
public class CityData
{
    private BaseData baseData;
    private int cases;
    //...
}
```

At this time, I can only request data for today. When I save a CityData-object in my db, it looks like this:

[image]

My next step: Save the data for the last 7 days. But: Firebase would also save the base data every day. **Can I prevent this** (=> only save when not exists or update when something changes)? **Otherwise, I have to change the data struct. But which is the best possibility?**
My first idea: Create two seperate paths like this:

[image]

But then, I have to extract BaseData from CityData and join them every time, for example when I need the city name, which is often. Is this the best way? It's my first time with NoSql, so every help would be nice!